# Efficient Matching Algorithm in R

Tags: r, algorithm, match

I have a data set with multiple columns, including ID, key 1, direction, date, size. I am trying to write an algorithm to create a GroupID for groups where I can match where direction is opposite, date is equivalent and I cannot match on partial size, though I can take two rows in the same direction to sum to match if the sizes are equivalent. I am also trying to maximize size. As an example below I would end up with GroupID 1 as below.

```
|ID |direction  |size   |key1   |date   |GroupID
--------------------------------------------------------
| 12345 |1  |100    |1.1    |01/01/2016 |1
| 22356 |0  |50     |1.1    |01/01/2016 |1
| 54686 |0  |50     |1.1    |01/01/2016 |1
| 78468 |1  |50     |5.2    |01/01/2016 |NA
```

Do people have some ideas about what might be an efficient way to write a way to create a GroupID for matches?

Secondly, were I able to do partial matches (much simpler problem) what would be the quickest way to do this?

```
|ID |direction  |size   |key1   |date   |GroupID
--------------------------------------------------------
| 12345 |1  |100    |1.1    |02/01/2016 |2
| 22356 |0  |50     |1.1    |02/01/2016 |2
| 54686 |0  |25     |1.1    |02/01/2016 |2
```

Comment: This may entail a somewhat comprehensive answer. What have you tried? Do you perhaps have a specific question?

Comment: Hello, please include a `dput` of your data set so it's easier for us to recreate in our R sessions